# "Web application version is unsupported" when creating a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets, netbeans

I am following the tutorial http://javanetbeans.net78.net/kb/60/web/tutorial-webapps.html

and when I get to the portion 'Creating a front controller using a servlet' I receive an error from Netbeans saying "Web application version is unsupported"

Using netbeans 6.8

Anyone able to explain why I am getting this prompt?

Here is the contents of my web-xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="/Midnight" version="2.5">
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which JavaEE version you have selected ?http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic22286.html

Comment: I selected Java EE 5 with Glass Fish v2.1

Comment: Can you post the contents of your web.xml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See what value is set for the 'version' attribute in the `<web-app>` element of your web.xml file. Here is an example from a version 2.5 web app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <!-- The rest of your web.xml content -->
</web-app>
```

Maybe yours is set to something else not supported by the container.

Comment: I was thinking this but changing the <web-app> tag to this^ doesn't help :( Perhaps it is something with the DOCTYPE?

Comment: Your DOCTYPE is for version 2.3, so pasting in my 2.5 <web-app> element will not be valid. 2.3 is pretty old, so I'm thinking that's not the version that it is complaining about... unless it is too old?

Comment: Try deleting the whole !DOCTYPE element and using the 2.5 <web-app> element.

Comment: Works perfectly :D Had to restart the IDE for the changes to stick but they did

Comment: Nice! I'm glad that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create Java Web Application project in NetBeans
2. Inside the Project there is folder called **Source Package**
3. Right click in default package which is located inside **source package**
   **new** → Servlet
4. In front of **Class Name**: provide the name for your Servlet and click **Next**
5. In the next page put the tick mark in front of **Add information to deployment descriptor (web.xml)** to generate automatically the `web.xml`.

[image]

This will give you a default (and nearly empty) `web.xml` file, of whatever version NetBeans decided to give you (rather than needing just version 2.3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.NewServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```