# Web application version is unsupported. Upgrade web.xml to version 2.4 or newer or use previous version of NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, web-applications

Web application version is unsupported. Upgrade web.xml to version 2.4 or newer or use previous version of NetBeans.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Web application version is unsupported" when creating a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369911/web-application-version-is-unsupported-when-creating-a-servlet)

Comment: You can also research the various answers in [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Web+application+version+is+unsupported.+site:stackoverflow.com).